# NPE при инициализации фрагментов

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение, в котором использую фрагменты на главного экране. Общая идея такова: на сервере 4 таблицы, данные из каждой таблицы приходят с сервера и отображаются на одном из фрагментов. Код привожу для для 1 табы, остальные 3 написаны также. Для инициализации фрагментов использую наследник класса FragmentPagerAdapter, данные принимаются в виде ArrayList.

```
public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Map<Integer, AbstractTabFragment> tabs;
private Context context;
private List<TournamentsDTO> data_tour;
private List<TeamsDTO> data_team;
private List<PlayersDTO> data_play;
private List<CommentatorsDTO> data_comm;
private  TournamentsFragment tournamentsFragment;
private TeamsFragment teamsFragment;
private PlayersFragment playersFragment;
private CommentatorsFragment commentatorsFragment;

public TabsFragmentAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.data_tour = new ArrayList<>();
    this.data_team = new ArrayList<>();
    this.data_play = new ArrayList<>();
    this.data_comm = new ArrayList<>();
    initTabs(context);
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return tabs.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.size();
}
private void initTabs(Context context) {
    tabs = new HashMap<>();
    tournamentsFragment = TournamentsFragment.getInstance(context, data_tour);
    teamsFragment = TeamsFragment.getInstance(context, data_team);
    playersFragment = PlayersFragment.getInstance(context, data_play);
    commentatorsFragment = CommentatorsFragment.getInstance(context, data_comm);
    tabs.put(0, tournamentsFragment);
    tabs.put(1, teamsFragment);
    tabs.put(2, playersFragment);
    tabs.put(3, commentatorsFragment);
}
public void setData_tour(List<TournamentsDTO> data_tour) {
    this.data_tour = data_tour;
    tournamentsFragment.refreshData(data_tour);
}
public void setData_team(List<TeamsDTO> data_team) {
    this.data_team = data_team;
    teamsFragment.refreshData(data_team);
}
public void setData_play(List<PlayersDTO> data_play) {
    this.data_play = data_play;
    playersFragment.refreshData(data_play);
}
public void setData_comm(List<CommentatorsDTO> data_comm) {
    this.data_comm = data_comm;
    commentatorsFragment.refreshData(data_comm);
}
```

Вот так выглядит инициализация каждого фрагмента

```
public class TournamentsFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_tournaments;
private List<TournamentsDTO> data_tour;
private TournamentsListAdapter tournamentsListAdapter;
public static TournamentsFragment getInstance(Context context, List<TournamentsDTO> data_tour)
{
    Bundle  args = new Bundle();
    TournamentsFragment tournamentsFragment = new TournamentsFragment();
    tournamentsFragment.setArguments(args);
    tournamentsFragment.setContext(context);
    tournamentsFragment.setData_tour(data_tour);   tournamentsFragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.fab_item_tournaments));
    return tournamentsFragment;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTour);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    tournamentsListAdapter = new TournamentsListAdapter(data_tour);
    rv.setAdapter(tournamentsListAdapter);
    return view;
}
private void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
private void setData_tour(List<TournamentsDTO> data_tour) {
    this.data_tour = data_tour;
}
public void refreshData(List<TournamentsDTO> list){
    tournamentsListAdapter.setData_tour(list);
    tournamentsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

А вот так они заполняются в MainActivity. Здесь привожу глобальные переменные, метод, который инициализирует табы и метод, который загружает данные из сервера. Данные приходят в виде массива, поэтому перевожу их в список.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsFragmentAdapter adapter1, adapter2, adapter3, adapter4;

private void initTabs() {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapter1 = new TabsFragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);

    new TournamentTask().execute();

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private class TournamentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, TournamentsDTO[]>{
    @Override
    protected TournamentsDTO[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        RestTemplate template1 = new RestTemplate();
        template1.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        return template1.getForObject(Constants.URL.GET_ALL_TOURNAMENTS_ITEM, TournamentsDTO[].class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TournamentsDTO[] tournamentsDTOs) {
        List<TournamentsDTO> listTour = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;

        while (count < tournamentsDTOs.length){
            listTour.add(tournamentsDTOs[count]);
            count++;
        }
        adapter1.setData_tour(listTour);
    }
}
```

Вот ошибки, которые появляются

```
Process: illidan.com.statisticsd2, PID: 5888
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                        at illidan.com.statisticsd2.fragments.TournamentsFragment.refreshData(TournamentsFragment.java:68)
                                                                        at illidan.com.statisticsd2.adapter.TabsFragmentAdapter.setData_tour(TabsFragmentAdapter.java:79)
                                                                        at illidan.com.statisticsd2.MainActivity$TournamentTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:169)
                                                                        at illidan.com.statisticsd2.MainActivity$TournamentTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:151)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: И еще забавно то, что пока работает код только для одной табы ошибок нет, а вот когда пытаюсь запустить 2 и больше - начинаются проблемы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы создали фрагменты в адаптере (TabsFragmentAdapter), но жизненный цикл для них еще не начался, т.е. onCreateView не вызывается, он вызывается только для текущего отображаемого фрагмента. В итоге у вас tournamentsListAdapter не инициализирован, а вы ему пытаетесь данные обновить.

Как вариант:

```
public void refreshData(List<TournamentsDTO> list){
    if(tournamentsListAdapter==null){
        data_tour = list; 
    } else {
        tournamentsListAdapter.setData_tour(list);
        tournamentsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Кроме того, вы неверно инициализируете фрагмент, фабричный метод getInstance должен только заполнять аргументы, остальные поля при пересоздании фрагмента (при повороте) будут очищены. Эти строки неверны:

```
tournamentsFragment.setContext(context);
tournamentsFragment.setData_tour(data_tour);      
tournamentsFragment.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.fab_item_tournaments));
```

Далее, контекст в фрагмент передавать не нужно, у фрагмента есть метод getContext(). Остальные данные либо сериализуйте (например, title можно в аргументы смело записать) в аргументы, либо взывайте соответствующие методы из активити (т.е. извне), учитывая (см. первый снипет), что фрагмент не обязательно отображается.

**UPD**

`getInstance` может выглядеть так:

```
public static TournamentsFragment getInstance(String title)
{
    Bundle  args = new Bundle();
    TournamentsFragment tournamentsFragment = new TournamentsFragment();
    args.putString("title", title);
    tournamentsFragment.setArguments(args);
    return tournamentsFragment;
}
```

Использовать так:

```
tournamentsFragment = TournamentsFragment.getInstance(
    context.getString(R.string.fab_item_tournaments));
```

Что касается данных, то в getInstance они не нужны, вы же все равно создаете фрагменты с пустыми списками и ждете их в AsyncTask... Надо смотреть адаптер списка, точнее метод setData_tour. Ну и вообще не видя полного вашего кода, предполагать можно многое... Воспользуйтесь отладчиком, посмотрите какие методы для какого фрагмента в каком порядке вызываются, заполняется ли список, обновляется ли адаптер и т.д.

ЗЫ Проанализируйте нужны ли вам переменные списков для данных в TabsFragmentAdapter, если вы все равно их транслируете в соответствующий фрагмент, а оттуда в адаптер.

Comment: С первой частью ответа все понятно, но я не могу понять как избавиться от этих трёх неверных строк. Кроме того, изменил refreshData() по Вашему совету и теперь данные отображаются только на одном из фрагментов, вне зависимости от того, какой из фрагментов сейчас показывается(ну хоть NPE нету теперь). Не могли бы Вы более подробно объяснить вторую часть совета, пожалуйста.

Comment: @IllidanStormrage обновил ответ.

Comment: Бесконечно Вам благодарен, проблема решилась. Когда подумал головой хватило даже первой части ответа(проверки на null). Но вот еще одна странность: когда перехожу из первой табы во вторую, а потом снова на первую, то данные на первой сохраняются. Когда с первой перехожу на вторую, а потом на третью, то на второй табе данные еще остаются, но вот на первой - удаляются.

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в реализации адаптера, т.е. фрагменты должны создаваться по мере необходимости viewPager'а. У вас фрагменты создаются заранее, viewpager лишние фрагменты удаляет. Попробуйте добавить `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` тогда ваши фрагменты удаляться не должны и данные останутся.